# C# Overloaded method error

Tags: c#

Hi I have just started learning WCF and I have encountered an error I do not understand.

This method returns an error saying:

> The best overloaded method match for "PersonKlient.ServiceReference1.PersonTjenesteGrensesnitt.searchAge(int)'
>   has some invalid arguments"

Here is the code

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var personer = _tjeneste.searchAge(textBox2.Text);

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var person in personer)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Fornavn + " " + person.EtterNavn);
        }
    }
```

However the method called is supposed to take a String argument. Not an int.

```
        public List<Person> searchAge(String age)
    {
        List<Person> result = new List<Person>();
        int numAge = Convert.ToInt32(age);

        foreach (Person person in personer)
        {
            if (person.Alder == numAge)
                result.Add(person);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you changed the service (to change the parameter from `int` to `string`) but not regenerated the proxy code? That would certainly explain it - regenerate the service reference, and all should be well.

Comment: I am also pretty new to Visual Studio so could you tell me how I can regenerate the reference?

Comment: @SvennK Right-click the reference and select 'Update Web/Service Reference' from the context menu.